# EF - Many-to-many configuration where both sides have same mapping property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to create a many-to-many mapping between User and Group models.  Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `Entity` abstract class to implement common properties in the classes that inherit from it.  In this case, `Id` will be the key property for all of my EF classes.

Here is my configuration file where I map the many-to-many relationship:

```
public GroupConfiguration()
{
    Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(databaseGeneratedOption: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();

    HasMany(g => g.Users)
        .WithMany(u => u.Groups)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("Id");
            m.MapRightKey("Id");
            m.ToTable("UserGroups");
        });
}
```

When I attempt to add a migration, I get the following error:  `Id: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Id' is already defined.`  It seemingly doesn't like the fact that the property being mapped on both sides has the same identifier.  When I don't inherit from `Entity` for one of the classes, eg. `User`, and make the mapping property `UserId` it is able to successfully create a migration.

Is there any way around this?  It would be to be able to use an `Id` property for all of my entities defined in an abstract class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 keys with the same name, it will represent the columns for your relationship table (named "UserGroups"). When you call "MapLeftKey" or "MapRightKey", you define the columns name.

So I suggest you to rename your Ids (UserId and GroupId for example) and your mapping should be alright. I think you cannot have another solution on using fluent API.

Comment: I see.  Your explanation of why it's not possible - because the identifiers are what is used as the column names in the relationship table - explains it.  Not sure why I didn't realize that. :P  Thanks!